# График платежей select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица по графику платежа:

```
| PaySum   | PlanDate   |
+----------+------------+ 
| 23928.38 | 14.10.2019 |
| 24347.13 | 12.11.2019 |
| 24773.20 | 12.12.2020 |
| 25206.73 | 13.01.2020 |
```

Нужно вытащить предстоящую сумму за 3 мес

Мой запрос к примеру:

```
select sum(s.PaySum)
  from L_DEA s
 where s.PlanDate between trunc(sysdate + 1) and
       ADD_months(trunc(sysdate + 1), 3)
   and ID = :iId;
```

Данный запрос вытаскивает 4 мес если запустить sysdate = 12.10.19 или 13.10.19
в остальных случаях показывает корректно за 3 месяца

Как можно правильно сформировать select

Comment: Три месяца при BETWEEN - это от "месяц" до "месяц + 2". А вовсе не плюс три.

Comment: Что за СУБД? Почему разные названия столбцов в таблице и в вашем запросе?

Comment: @edem, подправил

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали СУБД!  Вот вариант для *PostgreSQL*, но я не
использовал расширения, так что он должен работать для всех стандартных
*SQL*-СУБД:

```sql
SELECT SUM(PaySum)
  FROM l_dea AS s
 WHERE CAST(PlanDate AS DATE)
       BETWEEN DATE '2019-10-12' /* This is the CURRENT_DATE().  */
       AND DATE '2019-10-12' + INTERVAL 'P2M'
   AND id = $1;
;
```

*DB Fiddle*:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7R2ofXispDpFvgDYHPJfh/0.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.PlanDate, s.PaySum
  from L_DEA s
 inner join (select PlanDate
               from (select distinct s.PlanDate
                       from L_DEA s
                      where  ID = :iId
                        and s.PlanDate >= (to_date('10.10.2019'))
                      order by s.PlanDate) tt
              where rownum <= 3) A2
    on s.PlanDate = A2.PlanDate
 where ID = :iId);
```